# RegExp Pattern building

Tags: php, regex

Can you help me with making pattern for PHP. Here is the string:

```
08-12-2010 02:24 (<a href="http://somesite.com/mail/username/3605DAC793E904E7.html" fastLink="1">link</a>)
```

There are a lot of such strings and I have to parse them with given date and time. I need in **3605DAC793E904E7** from that string.

```
$Day = date("d");
$Month = date("m");
$Year = date("Y");
$Hour = date("H");
$Minute = date("i");

$linkPattern = "/{$Day}-{$Month}-{$Year}\ {$Hour}:{$Minute}*(.*)\.html/";
```

But that pattern won't work. Could you help me, please?

Comment: Are you trying to parse those strings with regular expressions?

Comment: @aefxx Yes, and don't speak, please, about parsing html-data with regular expressions.

Comment: Using regexp isn't bad per se. It always depends on what you're trying to do. In your case it seems to be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$reg = "/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}).*\/(.*)\.html/i";
```